# Call a service method using mock in unit test case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, c#-4.0, mocking

I need to Call a service method using mock in unit test case which pass through from controller. In internet most of the solutions are like, directly return service value. I need to call the service method from controller after called the controller method from unit test case. It should get the return values from DB.

//My Unit test case
**`var mapBlockServiceMock = new Mock(IMapBlockService)( );`**

//Here I am doing setup for services(but it will directly return a value)
**`mapBlockServiceMock.Setup(service => service.GetMapBlock(1))                 .Returns(GetMapBlockList());`**

**`var controller = new MapDashboardController(mapBlockServiceMock.Object);`**

```
int mapId = 1;   
 var values = controller.GetHomePage(mapId);
```

//My Controller
**`private readonly IMapBlockService mapblockservice;`**

```
public MapDashboardController(IMapBlockService mapblockservice)  
    {
       this.mapblockservice = mapblockservice  
    }
```

```
public HomePageViewModel GetHomePage ( int mapId )  
        {  
List<MapBlock> mapBlockList= new List<MapBlock>();  
mapBlockList = mapblockservice.GetMapBlock(mapId)  
}
```

Now using mock services, it should go to the mapblockservice.GetMapBlock.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Not seeing a problem statement. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @nkosi By using the unit test case code which written above, i cant able to access the service method, instead of I am just getting the return value what I am giving while setup(setup code also written above). So i need assistance to call a service method from unit test case using mock. Please see the comments of the code above for reference.